# GeoTag and Import Photo Plugin ERROR what Caused?

Tags: python, photos, geotag

An error occurred while executing the following Python code:

KeyError: 'USERPROFILE' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hermanguse/.qgis2/python/plugins/ImportPhotos/ImportPhotos.py", line 234, in toolButtonImport
    os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in **getitem**
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'USERPROFILE'

Python version: 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) [GCC 7.2.0] 
QGIS version: 2.14.18-Essen Essen, exported

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/hermanguse/.qgis2/python
/home/hermanguse/.qgis2/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2
/home/hermanguse/.qgis2//python
.
/home/hermanguse/.qgis2/python/plugins/gearthview/ext-libs
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools